# Get first 5 characters of number array element

Tags: arrays, angular

Here ,I want to get the first 5 characters in this array element

```
coordinates: [2.343400400000064, 48.8950025]
```

which will be displayed on the view as folows:

```
<p>
   {{ coordinates[1].substring(0,5) }}
   ,
   {{ coordinates[0].substring(0,5) }}
</p>
```

But it will give this error as follows:

```
ERROR TypeError: _v.parent.context.$implicit.coordinates[1].substring is not a function
```

Please help me with this

Answer (score 2):

Convert Number to String First.

Like

```
String(coordinates[0]).substring(0, 5);
```

`String` is `typecast` for converting any `datatype` to `string`.

[MDN String Typecast](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)

Answer (score 0):

You must convert the number to a String before extracting the substring :

```
String(coordinates[1]).substring(0,5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the numbers to string.

```
<p>
   {{ coordinates[1].toString().substring(0,5) }}
   ,
   {{ coordinates[0].toString().substring(0,5) }}
</p>
```

Or:

```
<p>
   {{ (coordinates[1] + '').substring(0,5) }}
   ,
   {{ (coordinates[0] + '').substring(0,5) }}
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just round off the number as this with the `decimal pipe` [Angular Decimal Pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe)

```
        <p>
          {{ location.location.coordinates[1] | number }}
          ,
          {{ location.location.coordinates[0] | number }}
        </p>
```

It works ...Thanks you all !!!